# Using DocRaptor web service with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to generate Excel (.xls) files from an AngularJS app using [DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/).  I keep getting the following error, when trying just the simple POST request as described in DocRaptor's Getting Started documentation.  Their documentation claims they support CORS requests.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Error Message in Chrome:

```
OPTIONS https://docraptor.com/docs?user_credentials=my-api-key

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docraptor.com/docs user_credentials=my-api-key. 

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Here's the JavaScript code in my AngularJS controller:

```
var forDocRaptor = {
    "doc" : {
        "test": true,
        "document_type": "pdf",
        //Just trying simple pdf for now
        "name": "adoc.pdf",
        "document_content": '<div>PDF generation test</div>',
        "strict": "none",
        "javascript": true,
        "tag": "tag",
        "async": false
    }
}   

$scope.exportToExcel = function() {

    $http.post('https://docraptor.com/docs?user_credentials=my-api-key', forDocRaptor)
        .success(function(res) {
            console.log(res)
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. You should be sending -

```
data:forDocRaptor
```

Also, for some reason if you use

```
method:'POST'
```

it works, but $http.post does not

So - your code would look like this:

```
$http({
     method:'POST',
     url: URL,
     data:forDocRaptor
  }).success(function(res){
     console.log(res)
})
```