# PDF generation with DocRaptor in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pdf-generation

I am trying to incorporate DocRaptor in my AngularJS project for PDF generation and exporting some pages as PDFs. I am fairly new to Angular and can't seem to find any supporting documentation. Could someone point me to the right resources.
The only resource I have found is this StackOverflow question: [Using DocRaptor web service with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219813/using-docraptor-web-service-with-angularjs).

Answer (score 3):

I'm a DocRaptor developer. We fully support Angular sites. The example given in the existing question you linked to is pretty good. You can also use the `document_url` field, instead of the `document_content` field, and just put in the url for your invoice/report page. Let me know or support know if we can be of further assistance.