# How to use docraptor with requirejs

Tags: angularjs, pdf-generation

I am writing an angular app and I am using requirejs for loading modules.

One of the main features of the app is to be able to print the some pages in the said app and I am trying to do the PDF generation thru Docraptor, but the problem is Docraptor doesn't seem to work with requirejs.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to setup something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDF generation with DocRaptor in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259975/pdf-generation-with-docraptor-in-angularjs)

Comment: @IoannisTziligkakis The difference is I'm trying to use requirejs for the module loading. Because it shows the styles but not the content, and I'm using ui router for the routing, that's why I think that it's because of requirejs

Comment: DocRaptor developer here. First, make sure JS is actually enabled and that you're using the latest pipeline version. If that's done, I'd look through your DocLog for debugging clues. If there aren't any errors there, I'd stop ignoring resource errors and see if that's the issue: https://docraptor.com/documentation/api#api_ignore_resource_errors. If none of that fixes the problem, contact support. I can't think of any reason DocRaptor would not support RequireJS. I'm confident many users have used it successfully before.